# Owlcarousel v1.3.3 - can't see next slide when dragging / grabbing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I took over a project with a hero slider and it is driving me a little crazy ;)

The slider is working, but I can't see the next image when I'm grabbing / dragging with the mouse/trying to swipe on the phone.
It's only showing my (black) background.

I am not sure if it has something to do with the transitioning or a wrong setup of the slider itself. But I've tried it with the example code from the theme and it will just not run smoothly on that page

It's the hero slider you can see when the page is loaded. The plugin is Owlcarousel in version 1.3.3

my page is https://apa.schneil.de

Any help or hint in the right direction would be amaaazing! :-)
Thank you a lot!

Comment: It's working for me in my device emulator in chrome

Comment: It may help to include the [relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here in your question so that others can reproduce and more easily investigate the problem.

Comment: Carousel slides that do not have the "active" class are hidden. Look for `.owl-item {opacity:0}` in your CSS bundle.

Comment: Thank you so much @showdev! You helped me a lot!